# What does the empty `()` do on a Matlab matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

In `Matlab`, what exactly does the expression `M()` do where `M` is a matrix?

```
>> M = magic(3);
>> M() 

ans =

     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

Is the expression `isequaln(M, M())` true under all circumstances? Is `M()` simply a copy of `M`, or an identical expression, or is there any context where referring to `M()` means something else than referring to `M`? Maybe in the case of operator overloading?

Comment: Except for the fact that it seems to work, I see no mention about this behavior in the documentation. Strange thing indeed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Besides the fact the it would give the default operation on some function, such as `rand()`, and easter eggs such as `imagesc()` and `spy()` (this will work also without the `()`) , it seems to be a more efficient way to access whole arrays as long as their dimensionality is below 5 (as @Rody Oldenhuis spotted) . For example:

```
a=rand(2^12);

tic
for j=1:1e5
a ;
end
toc

tic
for j=1:1e5
a(:)  ;
end
toc

tic
for j=1:1e5
a()   ; 
end
toc
```

yield:

```
Elapsed time is 0.047250 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.022260 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.011925 seconds.
```

However, for assignments there's very little difference  between `a1=a` vs `a1=a()`, where the latter is slower by 1.5%...

Perhaps this thread will answer some of your question regarding [operator overloading](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/108888).

Comment: +1, but try `a = rand(10,10,10,10,10);` and `a();` will be slower than `a;`...Matlab references data in mysterious ways :)

Comment: +1 Amazing Rody, amazing... though only in arrays of 5 or more dimensions will `a()` be slower (as I'm sure you already tested), below that `a()` still wins. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, no speed difference for me between methods 1 and 3 if you run it from within a function :) matlab 2011b, 64 bit, Linux.

Comment: @angainor: You mean calling a function inside a loop, where the function contains the `a;` or `a();`, or call the function which contains a loop, inside of which the `a;` or `a();` is called? Because in the former case the function call overhead probably outweighs any subtle differences in the `a;` or `a();` calls, and in the latter case, there is not much difference with natan's test here...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis No, I mean I copied natans code into a function, which is a JIT friendly approach and should probably always be used for such tests, and executed the above tests by calling the function. I see no difference between `a;` and `a();`, but `a(:);` is slower.

Comment: @angainor: AFAIK, JIT accellerates both scripts and functions...Why would it be more JIT-friendly to place it in a function?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis AFAIK JIT does distinguish between script/command line and functions. An example is [in-place function arguments](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/). If you run the `inplaceTest` contents from a script and not from a function - it does not work, i.e., the in-place optimization is not there. I am not saying this is the same case as here, just for safety I always use functions.