# In numpy, what does indexing an array with the empty tuple vs. ellipsis do?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I just discovered — by chance — that an array in `numpy` may be indexed by an empty tuple:

```
In [62]: a = arange(5)

In [63]: a[()]
Out[63]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I found some documentation on the [numpy wiki ZeroRankArray](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/ZeroRankArray):

> (Sasha) First, whatever choice is made for x[...] and x[()] they should be the same because ... is just syntactic sugar for "as many : as necessary", which in the case of zero rank leads to ... = (:,)*0 = (). Second, rank zero arrays and numpy scalar types are interchangeable within numpy, but numpy scalars can be use in some python constructs where ndarrays can't.

So, for 0-d arrays `a[()]` and `a[...]` are supposed to be equivalent. Are they for higher-dimensional arrays, too? They strongly appear to be:

```
In [65]: a = arange(25).reshape(5, 5)

In [66]: a[()] is a[...]
Out[66]: False

In [67]: (a[()] == a[...]).all()
Out[67]: True

In [68]: a = arange(3**7).reshape((3,)*7)

In [69]: (a[()] == a[...]).all()
Out[69]: True
```

**But**, it is *not* syntactic sugar. Not for a high-dimensional array, and not even for a 0-d array:

```
In [76]: a[()] is a
Out[76]: False

In [77]: a[...] is a
Out[77]: True

In [79]: b = array(0)

In [80]: b[()] is b
Out[80]: False

In [81]: b[...] is b
Out[81]: True
```

And then there is the case of indexing by an empty *list*, which does something else altogether, but appears equivalent to indexing with an empty `ndarray`:

```
In [78]: a[[]]
Out[78]: array([], shape=(0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), dtype=int64)

In [86]: a[arange(0)]
Out[86]: array([], shape=(0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), dtype=int64)

In [82]: b[[]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed.
```

So, it appears that `()` and `...` are similar but not quite identical and indexing with `[]` means something else altogether. And `a[]` or `b[]` are `SyntaxError`s. Indexing with lists is documented at [index arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays), and there is a short notice about indexing with tuples [at the end of the same document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#dealing-with-variable-numbers-of-indices-within-programs).

That leaves the question:

Is the difference between `a[()]` and `a[...]` by design? What is the design, then?

(Question somehow reminiscent of: [What does the empty `()` do on a Matlab matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13679749/974555))

**Edit:**

In fact, even *scalars* may be indexed by an empty tuple:

```
In [36]: numpy.int64(10)[()]
Out[36]: 10
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The treatment of `A[...]` is a special case, optimised to [always return `A` itself](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L991):

```
if (op == Py_Ellipsis) {
    Py_INCREF(self);
    return (PyObject *)self;
}
```

Anything else that should be equivalent e.g. `A[:]`, `A[(Ellipsis,)]`, `A[()]`, `A[(slice(None),) * A.ndim]` will instead return a *view* of the entirety of `A`, whose `base` is `A`:

```
>>> A[()] is A
False
>>> A[()].base is A
True
```

This seems an unnecessary and premature optimisation, as `A[(Ellipsis,)]` and `A[()]` will always give the same result (an entire view on `A`).  From looking at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/fa547b80f7035da85f66f9cbabc4ff75969d23cd it seems that it was originally required because indexing with `...` didn't work properly on 0d arrays (previously to https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/4156b241aa3670f923428d4e72577a9962cdf042 it would return the element as a scalar), then extended to all arrays for consistency; since then, indexing has been fixed on 0d arrays so the optimisation isn't required, but it's managed to stick around vestigially (and there's probably some code that depends on `A[...] is A` being true).

Comment: I believe this answer is probably outdated. As of Numpy 1.16.4 ```A[...] is A``` evaluates to ```False``` for me, for both 0-dim and multi-dim arrays.

Comment: Yeah, this special case has been gone for ages - in fact, I think the [commit](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/607863d7387e80dab4b064856b598a8c86e9bee4#diff-6c6d7467bec90e023c600b31f151a5b1) that took it out was just two months after this answer was originally posted.

Answer (score 5):

While in the example you've given, the empty tuple and ellipsis give a similar result, in general they serve different purposes. When indexing an array, `A[i, j, k] == A[(i, j, k)]` and specifically `A[...] == A[(Ellipsis,)]`. Here the tuple simply serves as a container for indexing elements. This can be useful when you need to manipulate the index as a variable, for example you can do:

```
index = (0,) * A.ndim
A[index]
```

Notice that because the tuple is the container for indexing elements, it cannot be combined with other indices, for example `A[(), 0] == A[[], 0]` and `A[(), 0] != A[..., 0]`.

Because an array `A` can be indexed with fewer indices than `A.ndim`, indexing with an empty tuple is a natural extension of that behavior and it can be useful in some situations, for example the above code snipit will work when `A.ndim == 0`.

In short, the tuple serves as a container for indexing elements, which is allowed to be empty, while the Ellipsis is one of the possible indexing elements.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [official Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#detailed-notes), the differences is clear:

> An empty (tuple) index is a full scalar index into a zero dimensional
>   array. **`x[()]` returns a scalar if `x` is zero dimensional and a view
>   otherwise.** On the other hand **`x[...]` always returns a view**.
>
> When an ellipsis (`...`) is present but has no size (i.e. replaces zero
>   `:`) the result will still always be an array. A view if no advanced
>   index is present, otherwise a copy.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> # ---------------------------------- #
>>> # when `x` is at least 1 dimensional #
>>> # ---------------------------------- #
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
>>> x.shape
(100,)
>>> x.ndim
1
>>> a = x[()]
>>> b = x[...]
>>> id(x), id(a), id(b)
(4559933568, 4561560080, 4585410192)
>>> id(x.base), id(a.base), id(b.base)
(4560914432, 4560914432, 4560914432)
>>> # ---------------------------- #
>>> # when `z` is zero dimensional #
>>> # ---------------------------- #
>>> z = np.array(3.14)
>>> z.shape
()
>>> z.ndim
0
>>> a = z[()]
>>> b = z[...]
>>> type(a), type(b)
(<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)
>>> id(z), id(a), id(b)
(4585422896, 4586829384, 4561560080)
>>> id(z.base), id(a.base), id(b.base)
(4557260904, 4557260904, 4585422896)
>>> b.base is z
True
```

Comment: As of Numpy 1.16.4 this seems to be the correct answer, the accepted answer is outdated. A[...] returns a view of A for any dimension, and it is not optimised to give back the same object. ```A[...] is A``` evaluates to False for all dimensions. A[()] returns a scalar only if A is 0 dimensional, which is probably the canonical way to "index into A" if A is 0-dim.