# What does "[()]" mean when called upon a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I just came across this piece of code:

```
x = np.load(lc_path, allow_pickle=True)[()]
```

And I've never seen this pattern before: `[()]`. What does it do and why is this syntacticly correct?

---

```
a = np.load(lc_path, allow_pickle=True)
>>> array({'train_ppls': [1158.359413193576, 400.54333992093854, ...],
 'val_ppls': [493.0056070137404, 326.53203520368623, ...],
 'train_losses': [340.40905952453613, 675.6475067138672, ...],
 'val_losses': [217.46258735656738, 438.86770486831665, ...],
 'times': [19.488852977752686, 20.147733449935913, ...]}, dtype=object)
```

So I guess `a` is a `dict` wrapped in an array for some reason by the person who saved it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In numpy, what does indexing an array with the empty tuple vs. ellipsis do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689270/in-numpy-what-does-indexing-an-array-with-the-empty-tuple-vs-ellipsis-do)

Comment: Partly, I guess I'll edit a little my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It a way (the only way) of indexing a 0d array:

```
In [475]: x=np.array(21)                                                                       
In [476]: x                                                                                    
Out[476]: array(21)
In [477]: x.shape                                                                              
Out[477]: ()
In [478]: x[()]                                                                                
Out[478]: 21
```

In effect it pulls the element out of the array.  `item()` is another way:

```
In [479]: x.item()                                                                             
Out[479]: 21
In [480]: x.ndim                                                                               
Out[480]: 0
```

In

```
x = np.load(lc_path, allow_pickle=True)[()]
```

most likely the `np.save` was given a non-array; and wrapped in a 0d object dtype array to save it.  This is a way of recovering that object.

```
In [481]: np.save('test.npy', {'a':1})                                                         
In [482]: x = np.load('test.npy', allow_pickle=True)                                           
In [483]: x                                                                                    
Out[483]: array({'a': 1}, dtype=object)
In [484]: x.ndim                                                                               
Out[484]: 0
In [485]: x[()]                                                                                
Out[485]: {'a': 1}
```

In general when we index a nd array, e.g. `x[1,2]` we are really doing `x[(1,2)]`, that is, using a tuple that corresponds to the number of dimensions. If `x` is 0d, the only tuple that works is an empty one, `()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's indexing the array with a tuple of 0 indices. For most arrays, this just produces a view of the whole array, but for a 0-dimensional array, it extracts the array's single element as a scalar.

In this case, it looks like someone made the weird choice to dump a non-NumPy object to an array with `numpy.save`, resulting in NumPy saving a 0-dimensional array of `object` dtype wrapping the original object. The use of `allow_pickle=True` and the empty tuple index extracts the object from the 0-dimensional array.

They probably should have picked something other than `numpy.save` to save this object.